# Rhetorical term for repetition for clarification?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

In Malcolm X's Ballot or the Bullet speech, at one point he states: '*...dripping with blood, dripping with the blood of the black man...*.

Is there a specific rhetorical term for this technique, where a phrase is repeated to provide clarification?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_rhetorical_terms

Comment: I'd already had a look through this, and cmd-f for 'rep' and a couple of other words didn't show anything that seemed particularly relevant (beyond repetition itself, but I was looking for something more specific). Maybe symploce, but it's not quite capturing the entire essence; specifically that it is repeated to provide further clarification.

Comment: It's good to show your work in the question, along with why  those other definitions weren't useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, it looks like an example of "**Epimone**" which is **repetition of a phrase** (usually a question) **to stress a point**. In this case though, the repetition is not a question, it is the direct repetition of a phrase **to stress an additional meaningful descriptor** of the same phrase.

In your example, the "***clarification***" comes from the ***repetition + further description***. There are several other rhetorical terms pertaining to repetition listed at the link below.

https://literarydevices.net/repetition/